# How to count input values automatically and replace it without regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have set the function to replace **`{1}`** into **`$param1`** like this:

```php
<?php
$lang = '{1} say not exist!';
$replaceParam = 'aaa';
function languageParam($value, $param)
{
    $value = preg_replace("/\{(.+?)\}/s", $param, $value);
    return $value;
}

echo languageParam($lang, $replaceParam );
```

I want to know if it's possible to replace the string by this specific format:
`{numbers}`
Like this:

```php
<?php
$lang = '{1} say {2} not exist!';
$param = array(
    '1' => 'aaa',
    '2' => 'bbb'
);
```

I means, how to make the function can count input array and replace them by numbers?

For example:

```php
<?php
$lang = '{1} say {2} {3} {4}'; //maybe have {5}, {6}...etc
$param = array(
    '1' => 'aaa',
    '2' => 'bbb',
    '3' => 'ccc',
    '4' => 'ddd'
//and '5', '6'...etc
);
```

And it will output

```
aaa say bbb ccc ddd //....and more
```

Is it possible? Or it can work but will cost long time to count and search the strings?

Comment: Have you considered simply using formatted strings ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes, but in this case I'm using the string in my `$lang` array, and the input value was just that simple in my project, so I think the answer was just enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through the array and then do a string replace on the value you need to replace, using the index of the array:

```
<?php
$lang = '{1} say {2} {3} {4}'; 
$param = array(
    '1' => 'aaa',
    '2' => 'bbb',
    '3' => 'ccc',
    '4' => 'ddd'
);

foreach($param as $index => $p) {
  $lang = str_replace('{' . $index . '}', $p, $lang);
}

echo $lang; //aaa say bbb ccc ddd
```

Personally, I would use square brackets...

```
<?php
$lang = '[1] say [2] [3] [4]'; 
$param = array(
    '1' => 'aaa',
    '2' => 'bbb',
    '3' => 'ccc',
    '4' => 'ddd'
);

foreach($param as $index => $p) {
  $lang = str_replace("[$index]", $p, $lang);
}

echo $lang; //aaa say bbb ccc ddd
```

You can avoid breaking out the string then.

**With string indexes and numeric:**

```
<?php

$lang = '{char_1} say {2} {char_3} {4}'; 
$param = array(
    'char_1' => 'aaa',
    '2' => 'bbb',
    'char_3' => 'ccc',
    '4' => 'ddd'
);

foreach($param as $index => $p) {
  $lang = str_replace('{' . $index . '}', $p, $lang);
}

echo $lang; //aaa say bbb ccc ddd
```

Comment: This answer get better performance (time & memory) then using `preg_replace_callback` , but my project would use not only numbers but also some words like `Character_1 =>  'John'`

Comment: You can have string indexes and it will work the same?

Comment: So yeah, definitely a better solution than using preg_replace_callback but up to OP to develop their own best practices xD!

Comment: OMG, it works!! And faster then `preg_replace` !! Best answer !!